# "No WatchKit 1.0 app bundle found for app" Xcode 10.1 Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to upload an update for my app which involves new apple watch capabilities. I've managed to get the apple watch working as desired and have made several archives but keep getting notifications upon uploading that there is no apple watch app included. I've tried to troubleshoot the issue by making sure my bundle identifiers are correct (as I was getting an issue regarding this). I managed to fix that error but now right before installing the app I get this error

> No WatchKit 1.0 app bundle found for app
>   com.*mydomain*.*myapp*.watchkitapp.watchkitextension

I want to be able to upload my app and my watchkit app for a new release for my app although am unable to build because of the error, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had included the watch's binary in the main app's target. I did this because when I uploaded it to the app store it gave me an error saying that there was no app kit app. Once I removed the binary and reset the defaults to the info.plists it was fixed.

Note, it looks like the message on app store connect was a bug as the app works fine in testflight.

Answer (score 6):

If you have this error with SwiftUI and previews, make sure you have the right target selected, since Previews will try to compile to the selected target.

I had the iPhone simulator selected instead of the watch simulator and I was getting this error.